# Making more variables with variables

Tags: java

I have a loop that I want to keep creating more instance variables. For instance:

```
char K;
String Key = null;
while (Key == null)
{
    Key = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert key");
    int nextChar = 0;
    int CharAt = 0;
    int loop = 0; 
    while (loop == 0)
    {
        K(nextChar) =  Key.charAt(CharAt);
        nextChar = nextChar + 1;
        if (CharAt == null)
        {
            loop = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use this loop and the `nextChar` int to create more variables. This will keep doing so until it reaches the end of the string, which will cause the `CharAt` to go to null, which in turn activates the `if` statement, causing the loop to stop.

The code above obviously doesn't work. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You're looking for collections. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change `while (Key == null)` to `if (Key == null)`. This way, when `key` will be `null`, the `JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert key");` will be shown prompting the user for a key.

The string `key` will now contain the user's input.

Now to go over each of the characters in the key...

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < key.length() ; i++) {
    char c = key.charAt(i);
}
```